# ¿Como evitar repetir dato previo en un SELECT por cosulta MYSQL?

Tags: php, html, mysql, mvc

Estoy trabando por mvc y tengo el siguiente codigo en el cual traigo los nombres de *clientes* pero a la vez el cliente que la tabla *progreso* este se tomo igual de la tabla cliente, por lo que hago es imprimir el cliente de la tabla progreso y el de el resto de los clientes disponibles (esto lo hago porque estoy en un sección de editar el cual pueden cambiar de cliente si quieren), bueno al momento de imprimir ambos pongo una condición el cual le digo que si el nombre del cliente de la tabla cliente es igual al cliente de la tabla progreso solo muestre el cliente de la tabla progreso y ademas el resto de los clientes disponibles, pero al momento de hacer esto, me muestra el resto de los clientes y el de la tabla progreso, ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

```
<!--=====================================
            ENTRADA DEL CLIENTE
            ======================================-->
            <?php
             $item = "idPro";
                $valor = $_GET["idProgreso"];

                $progreso = ControladorProgreso::ctrMostrarProgresos($item, $valor);
              ?> 

            <div class="form-group">

              <div class="input-group">

                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></span>

                <select class="form-control" id="seleccionarCliente" name="seleccionarCliente" required>

                <option value="<?php echo $cliente["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $progreso["cliente"]; ?></option>

                <?php

                  $item = null;
                  $valor = null;

                  $categorias = ControladorClientes::ctrMostrarClientes($item, $valor);

                   foreach ($categorias as $key => $value) { if($value["nombre"] == $progreso["cliente"]) {?>

                     <option value="<?php echo $value["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $progreso["cliente"]; ?></option>

                   <?php }else{ ?>

                    <option value="<?php echo $value["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $value["nombre"]; ?></option>

                   <?php } 
                 } ?>

                </select>

              </div>

            </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es que me muestre el cliente de la tabla progreso, pero igual el resto de los clientes de la la tabla clientes pero que no suceda el error que se ve arriba.

Comment: Te esta tirando errores esas pagina.. no puede ser por culpa de eso lo que te pasa?

Comment: no esos no, son solo varibles que no he definido aun

Comment: Explica linea por linea la logica de tu codigo, creo que el problema esta ahi...

Comment: ¿El cliente de *progreso* debe ser la primer opción?

Comment: asi es debe de ser el primero seleccionado

Comment: Ya lo solucione, quite lo que el compañero @John56 puso de respuesta y en el if en el primer option le puse un selected y en el otro input no

Answer (score 0):

tengo una duda el error es que te publica dos veces el nombre, es que no queda del todo claro? pero si es eso veo que en el select en la parte de arriba tambien pones la opcion de imprimir el cliente progreso, entonces es quitar esa opcion, por el momento solo la comente.

```
            $progreso = ControladorProgreso::ctrMostrarProgresos($item, $valor);
          ?> 

        <div class="form-group">

          <div class="input-group">

            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></span>

            <select class="form-control" id="seleccionarCliente" name="seleccionarCliente" required>

          <!--  <option value="<?php echo $cliente["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $progreso["cliente"]; ?></option> -->

            <?php

              $item = null;
              $valor = null;

              $categorias = ControladorClientes::ctrMostrarClientes($item, $valor);

               foreach ($categorias as $key => $value) { if($value["nombre"] == $progreso["cliente"]) {?>

                 <option value="<?php echo $value["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $progreso["cliente"]; ?></option>

               <?php }else{ ?>

                <option value="<?php echo $value["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $value["nombre"]; ?></option>

               <?php } 
             } ?>

            </select>

          </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: si asi es me lo duplica, pero igual ya intento eso de comentarlo, solo me aparece la lista de los clientes.

Comment: has un error_log, para saber que valores pasan por $value["nombre"] y asi darte cuenta si empata con $progreso["cliente"].